# regular expression to match english words with some other characters

Tags: regex

I use this regular expression: `^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$` to match English phrases, however, I want this expression to match English phrases that **may contain some or all of these characters** at the beginning, between or at the end of them:
`? > < ; , { } [ ]  - _ + = ! @ # $ % ^ & * | '` and also the space character.

how can I update this regular expression to satisfy this requirement ?

thank you so much in advance ...

Comment: Are you matching words or phrases?

Comment: Oh god. Why not use `^.*$` as a patter. It'll match all.

Comment: @Shiplu: What's the purpose of matching against ^.*$ since it matches all ?

Comment: @Karolos, thats why its in a comment. What the OP is asking is not equivalent to `^.*$`.

Comment: @Shiplu: In some sense it does, because (almost) all characters are specified, there is no space requirement in it, nor a mention of \w or \p.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could simply add all your desired characters to your character class.

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9?><;,{}[\]\-_+=!@#$%\^&*|']*$
```

You will need to escape the following characters with a backslash, since they are considered as metacharacters inside character classes: `]`, `-`, `^`.

Note that your regex will also match empty strings, since it uses the `*` quantifier. If you only want to match words having at least one character, replace it with the `+` quantifier.

Answer (score 4):

You are looking for this pattern.

```
^[\s\w\d\?><;,\{\}\[\]\-_\+=!@\#\$%^&\*\|\']*$
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm thankfully accept the `\s\w\d` groups from the previous answer, and add other delimiters and special characters as hexadecimal ASCII ranges (you can use Unicode ranges as well):

```
^[\s\w\d\x21-\x2f\x3a-\x40\x5b-\x60\x7b-\x7e]*$
```

You can refer here to the [ASCII Codes](https://ascii.cl/)
and [Unicode characters](https://unicode-table.com/en/)