# Textbox IMEMode Setting it to Type Hiragana

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2012, textbox, ime

I want to type Hiragana charcaters in a textbox but it won't work even if I change both the form's and textbox's IMEMode to Hiragana. It only works if I manually set my computer's IME to Hiragana. Does someone knows how to type in Hiragana in a textbox when the textbox is in focus?

Note: To be clear, I want to type Hiragana while my computer's locale is still in English.

Comment: So you want to type Japanese characters when computer's locale is kept as English?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just install a Japanese input language, and make sure to place a tick beside Microsoft IME. Switch to Japanese layout, as needed, and make sure the IME setting is set to Hiragana. You can try other settings from there, just saying which worked for me.

Works everywhere - notepad, Word etc., including in TextBox inside VB.NET application - you don't need to change IMEMode of the control.

[image]

To add an input language in Windows 7, go to:

- Region and Language -> Keyboards and Languages -> Change Keyboards -> Add

Comment: Yep I know how to do that. What I'm asking is that without manually setting the computer's IME to Hiragana. Because I need to use it in a  VB + DB project. Is it possible to do that automatically?

Comment: @hajime_saitou: Let's reduce the scope a bit. Which of the following do you want to happen automatically? Install a Japanese input layout, then uninstall it when leaving the text, switching to Japanese layout and then back, or switching **user's** IME to Hiragana and back (or something else - please specify)?

Comment: Ok. I want to do is when the focus got on that specific textbox, the user will be able to type in Hiragana and when the focus is lost on that textbox and transferred to the another textbox, the input text will be back to default. I want to do it with the system still in English and without setting the computer's keyboard manually.

Comment: @hajime_saitou: I don't think it's possible like that, unless you create your own typeset, and handle all the drawing of Hiragana characters manually. My suggestion - stick to UI development guidelines and leave it up to the user when to switch the layout. If they want to type Hiragana in other textboxes as well - let them do it, but perhaps validate the input first.

Comment: I see. So the best thing I can do is validate the characters/text they have input is hiragana or not. Right? Thanks by the way.

Comment: @hajime_saitou: Yep, this sounds like your best option. And I would validate as non-English, so you don't have Hiragana in code. You can use Regex. [This should get you started](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8961833/regular-expression-to-match-english-words-with-some-other-characters). If you find my answer helpful, please accept and/or upvote.